# MTM as a IT ticketing system

Tags: test-design

Can MTM be configured as a IT ticketing system ? I have had success with TFS as a ticketing system and would like to scratch MTM off my list.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

To expand: MTM is (or was, given that Microsoft is aiming to replace MTM functionality with the TFS/VSTS/Azure DevOps web portal) the test management and execution part of the MS development ecosystem. More, MTM can't run without a connection to some version of TFS, be it an in-house server or the Azure DevOps (the new name for VSTS) team site.

While you could, theoretically, create test plans and test suites to cover your IT ticketing categories, then use test cases as a proxy for the actual tickets, this is an extremely expensive and inefficient way to use a tool designed to manage running tests, particularly when you need the highest level of MSDN subscription to use MTM in the first place.

You would do better to use TFS to manage your lifecycle and let any test cases in MTM be connected to your TFS work items.